# Polymer update class on click

Tags: javascript, polymer, refresh, components

I have polymer component that is designed to take an array of tabs and build nav tab list. I got to successfully build out the tabs but my issue is whenever I click on a tab my active class is not moving over to it. Any help would be fantastic!

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="basic-nav">
  <template>
    <style>
      .active{
        color: red;
      }
    </style>

    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{tabs}}">
      <button class$="{{isActive(item.key, 'btn btn-underline')}}" on-click="changeTab">
          {{item.label}} {{item.key === tab}}
      </button>
    </template>

  </template>


  <script>
  Polymer({
    is: "basic-nav",
    properties:{
      tab: {
        type: String,
        notify: true
      }
    },
    isActive: function(key, constants){
      var classList = '';
      classList += constants || '';
      if (key === this.tab) classList += ' active';
      return classList;
    },
    changeTab: function(e){
      this.tab = e.model.item.key;
    },
    ready: function() {
      this.tabs = [
        {key: 'A',label: 'sweet'},
        {key: 'B',label: 'nice'}
      ];
    }
  });
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in how computed bindings work.

In your code, you use the `isActive` function to compute the `class` attribute for the button, but the problem here is that it's only being called once because *computed bindings are only recomputed when one of the parameters the function is changed and every parameter is defined*.

So, since your `isActive` function only receives the `key` and the `constants` and those never change in the code here, it will be computed only when the element instance is created because your `changeTab` function only changes the `tab` property.

To get the desired behavior, you could add `tab` as a parameter to the `isActive` function as follows, just bear in mind you should also give the `tab` a default value for the computed binding to be performed in that case.

```
 <!-- Button html -->
<button class$="{{isActive(item.key, 'btn btn-underline', tab)}}" on-click="changeTab">
      {{item.label}} {{item.key === tab}}
  </button>

 <!-- Javascript function-->
isActive: function(key, constants, tab){
  var classList = '';
  classList += constants || '';
  if (key === tab) classList += ' active';
  return classList;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ju035h5u/) with everything working.

Comment: That worked!!!!! Thank you soo much!!! So it only reruns if a parameter changes. That correct?

Comment: Exactly, here's the guide article on [computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed) if you want more info on that

Answer (score 0):

here, key is item.key and you are doing comparison by the reference, not the values.

```
if (key === this.tab) classList += ' active';
```

Im not sure what the value of key is here, but Im assuming its the tabs name, inwhich case perhaps try

```
if (key === this.tab.type) { ... }
```

Comment: tab is holding the key. A better name for tab should be tabKey. Any thoughts why it does not rerun "isActive()" when I click on a button?